# Compiling aircrack-ng with mpicc

Tags: c++, c, mpi

When I try to compile aircrack-ng.c with mpicc I get the error:

Undefined function _REVISION

If I try to point mpicc at the makefile I get a syntax error.

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I’m trying to compile aircrack-ng to run with KestralHPC. I'm using ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use `make` from the top level to compile (there should be README or INSTALL files that say this?). You probably need to change CC to be mpicc instead of gcc, wherever that gets defined (in the package I got, it was in common.mak).